# wso2 stratos server & developer studio

Tags: wso2, wso2-stratos

is there anyway to run WSO2 Stratos server from Developer Studio?

I saw there is maven plugin available but didn't see any example. Please share if somebody has done before.

Answer (score 1):

Stratos is not a single server. It's a combination of services running on different JVM instances. Thus, cannot run from Developer Studio.